# MSSQL rounds decimals

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having an issue with my Database.
I am trying to save a decimal value in my decimal column of the table. This is how I get the value to be added:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Galleries/" + foto.Gallery + "/" + newFile));
foto.AspectRatio = (decimal)img.Width / (decimal)img.Height;
```

At this point the value will be something like `0.834231235232`. But when saving the the Database it gets rounded to 2 decimal places `0.8300000000`. 
The Decimal scale and precision are set to `decimal(18,18)`.

Why is this happening? Could it be Entity Framework loosing those extra decimalpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your field in c# is a `decimal` type, it will by default act like `decimal(18,2)` in the database, but you can override it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<NameOfEntity>()
                .Property(p => p.NameOfProperty)
                .HasPrecision(18, 18); // or whatever your schema specifies
}
```